# My fragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I created a very simple fragment to test my app and I got the following error message:

```
03-31 16:04:39.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7860): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.team3.domore/com.team3.domore.TabActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.team3.domore.SomeFrag cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

My fragment is really simple...

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SomeFrag extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_frag, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

Please help...I've been struggling with this for almost two hours..

EDIT: I'm pretty sure where I called this fragment (an activity that extends FragmentActivity) is working... just this fragment part is not working...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your `SomeFrag` extends

```
android.app.Fragment
```

as stated in the imports. Change the import to

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

and the cast will succeed.

Comment: Weird, I know this post was old. But for a newer version of android studio it was the opposite. I changed android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment

Comment: I had the same issue but doing as u said did remove the error but my app stated crashing for some reason..

Comment: Why is android studio creating `android.app.fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` by default?

Answer (score 17):

try changing following import

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`